# What are the solutions of $\sinh(z)=\frac{i}{2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find what are the solutions of $\sinh(z)=\frac{i}{2}$,
I reached the equation: $\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}=\frac{i}{2}$ and then by substituting : $t=e^z$, I got that $e^z=\frac{i}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ or $e^z=\frac{i}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. 
from here we can say that:  $$z_1=\ln\left|\frac{i}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right| + i\frac{5\pi}{6}+2\pi ik$$

$$z_2=\ln\left|\frac{i}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right| + i\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi ik$$

but in the solution they said that because of the identity $\sinh(z)=-i\sin(iz)$ we can conclude that the solutions are only purley imaginary.

I can't detect the bug in my solution.

Comment: Try computing $\ln|\frac{i}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|$

Comment: Why do you think your solutions aren't purely imaginary?

Comment: Oh, so silly of me :) , thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach is to write $z=x+iy$ and use the addition argument formula $\sinh(x+iy)=\sinh(x)\cos(y)+i\cosh(x)\sin(y)$.

Setting $\sinh(z)=i/2$ yields the pair of equations

$$\begin{align}
\sinh(x)\cos(y)&=0\tag1\\\\
\cosh(x)\sin(y)&=\frac12\tag2
\end{align}$$

From $(1)$, we have either $x=0$, $y=(2n-1)\pi/2$, or both.  From $(2)$, if $x=0$, then $y=\frac{\pi}{6}+2n\pi$ or $-\frac{\pi}{6}+(2n-1)\pi$.  And there is no solution if $y=(2n-1)\pi/2$.

> **Therefore, the possible solutions are $x=0$ and either $y=\frac{\pi}{6}+2n\pi$ or $y=-\frac{\pi}{6}+(2n-1)\pi$.**

Answer (score 0):

Let's see.

You have
$t-1/t = i$
or
$t^2-it-1 = 0$.

Solving,
$t
=\dfrac{i\pm\sqrt{i^2+4}}{2}
=\dfrac{i\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}
$.

If $e^z = t$,
if $z = u+iv$,
$e^z
=e^u(\cos v + i \sin v)
$.
Since
$|t| = 1$,
$u = 0$.

Therefore $z$ is
purely imaginary.